# Multiple json from a database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, inner-join

I have two tables ERRORS and PRODUCTS, they are related by two columns (error_code and issue) I want to get a response json using php. These are my files:

**Tables**:

ERRORS:

| id_error | error_code | issue | cause | solution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A01 | issue1 | cause1.1 | solution1.1 |
| 2 | A01 | issue1 | cause1.2 | solution1.2 |
| 3 | A01 | issue1 | cause1.3 | solution1.3 |
| 4 | A02 | issue2 | cause2.1 | solution2.1 |

PRODUCTS:

| id_error | product | issue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | P1 | issue1 |
| A01 | P2 | issue1 |
| A02 | P1 | issue2 |

This is my **.php file**

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
//$tipo = $_GET['txtTi'];
$array = array();   
if ($resultset = getSQLResultSet("
    SELECT errors.error_code,
           errors.issue,
           errors.cause,
           errors.solution,
           products.error_code,
           products.product,
           products.issue 
    FROM errors 
    JOIN products
        ON errors .issue = products.issue
            AND errors.error_code = products.error_code
    WHERE errors.error_code = 'A01'")
){
    $p = array();
    $c = array ();
    $s = array();
    while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        $e = array();
        $e['error_code'] = $row[0];
        $e['issue'] = $row[1];
        $c['cause'] = $row[2];
        $e['cause'] = $c;
        $s['solution'] = $row[3];
        $e['solution'] = $s;
        $p['product'] = $row[5];
        $e['products'] = $p;
        array_push($array,$e);
    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
?>
```

I have this **json**:

```
[
   {
      "error_code":"A01",
      "issue":"issue1",
      "cause":{
         "cause":"cause1.1"
      },
      "solution":{
         "solution":"solution1.1"
      },
      "products":{
         "product":"P1"
      }
   },
{
      "error_code":"A01",
      "issue":"issue1",
      "cause":{
         "cause":"cause1.2"
      },
      "solution":{
         "solution":"solution1.2"
      },
      "products":{
         "product":"P1"
      }
   },{
      "error_code":"A01",
      "issue":"issue1",
      "cause":{
         "cause":"cause1.3"
      },
      "solution":{
         "solution":"solution1.3"
      },
      "products":{
         "product":"P1"
      }
   },
(...)

]
```

But this is the **json** that I want

```
[
{
 "error_code":"A01",
 "issue":"issue1",
 "cause":{
         "cause":"cause1.1",
         "cause":"cause1.2",
         "cause":"cause1.3"
          },
 "solution":{
          "solution":"solution1.1",
          "solution":"solution1.2",
          "solution":"solution1.3"
          },
 "products":{
          "product":"P1",
          "product":"P2"
          }
       }
]
```

Comment: Are the db relations involved in your expected result ? If not, you could just fetch all rows in each table, right ?

Comment: *they are related by two columns (error_code and issue)* This combinatoin is not unique in either tables. So you must obtain distinct values pairs in separate subquery and use it as a base.

Comment: @AymDev they are involved by the columns error_code and issue, to get the product that I need. And then I want to retrieve all products in an array in the json

Comment: @Akina what do you mean with separate subquery and use it as a base? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: You cannot have duplicated keys in the same array level.  For example, you cannot have `solution` and `solution` as keys in the same subarray.  I recommend that you just make indexed subarrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could group your database rows and comma-delimit them so that they are flat, then unpack/explode them as you iterate.

```
SELECT errors.error_code,
       errors.issue,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT errors.cause) AS causes,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT errors.solution) AS solutions,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products.product) AS products
FROM errors 
JOIN products
    ON errors.issue = products.issue
       AND errors.error_code = products.error_code
WHERE errors.error_code = 'A01'
GROUP BY errors.error_code,
         errors.issue;
```

| error_code | issue | causes | solutions | products |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | issue1 | cause1.1,cause1.2,cause1.3 | solution1.1,solution1.2,solution1.3 | P1,P2 |
| A01 | issue2 | cause1.4 | solution1.4 | P4 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uiMprg4DubvsgS28pd6gB6/0)

```
$result = [];
while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = [
        'error_code' => $row['error_code'],
        'issue' => $row['issue'],
        'causes' => explode(',', $row['causes']),
        'solutions' => explode(',', $row['solutions']),
        'products' => explode(',', $row['products'])
    ];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

There will be a few ways to do this.  The above is just one way.

Comment: but if I do that, I will have repetitive causes, solutions and products

Comment: I mean, I just tried. And I have every cause and every solution repeating twice. And the products many times. I just want to have a list with the multiple causes that exist, but not repeated

Comment: maybe this will help you (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df062ee811dc8c5c334e643a0ede56be)

Comment: Okay, I've adjusted it now.

Answer (score 0):

Query the data in the next form:

```sql
SELECT error_code, issue, cause, NULL solution, NULL product
FROM ERRORS
UNION ALL
SELECT error_code, issue, NULL, solution, NULL
FROM ERRORS
UNION ALL
SELECT id_error, issue, NULL, NULL, product
FROM PRODUCTS
ORDER BY error_code, issue, cause IS NULL, solution IS NULL
```

(see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e18d4ebde87144d35bca373ffdc7744)), then iterate this rowset in your PHP code.

PS. You cannot aggregate this data into needed JSON on MySQL due to key names duplication.

Comment: And how can I iterate this in my PHP code? Sorry, but I don't know PHP :(

Comment: @CeliaD I don't use (and hence don't know) it too. Cannot help, sorry.